# PHP mysqli_stmt_execute() error

Tags: php, sql

I am getting the following errors when I attempt to submit my form:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in                 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/editprofilephp.php on line 66

Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/editprofilephp.php on line 68
Error Occurred

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/editprofilephp.php on line 83

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/editprofilephp.php on line 85
```

I have checked all of the other posts with the same error and I have not made any of the mistakes mentioned in those.

My PHP is:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



$data_missing = array();    

if(empty($_POST['aboutme'])){

    // Adds name to array
    $data_missing[] = 'aboutme';

} else {

    // Trim white space from the name and store the name
    $aboutme = trim($_POST['aboutme']);

}

if(empty($_POST['full_name'])){

    // Adds name to array
    $data_missing[] = 'full_name';

} else {

    // Trim white space from the name and store the name
    $full_name = trim($_POST['full_name']);

}

if(empty($_POST['friend'])){

    // Adds name to array
    $data_missing[] = 'friend';

} else {

    // Trim white space from the name and store the name
    $friend = trim($_POST['friend']);

}





    if(empty($data_missing)){
    $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];    

    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

    $query = "UPDATE userprofile SET full_name='{$full_name}' aboutme='{$aboutme}'  friend='{$friend}' WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);


    //i Interger
    //d Doubles         
    //s Everything Else



    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

    if($affected_rows == 1){

        echo 'Student Entered';



        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    } else {

        echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
        echo mysqli_error();

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    }

} else {

    echo 'You need to enter the following data<br />';

    foreach($data_missing as $missing){

        echo "$missing<br />";

    }

}

}else {
echo mysqli_error();
}         

?>
```

I have used this code before in previous sections of the website for different purposes and I have not had any problems. I have spent a long time trying to locate the error and had no success, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Why are you preparing a statement *without* `?`s in it?  Concatenating user-entered values into your SQL query is a terrible idea since you have no escaping or sanitization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by an error in your SQL; because of the error, the statement fails to prepare.

Your query:

```
$query = "UPDATE userprofile SET full_name='{$full_name}' aboutme='{$aboutme}'  friend='{$friend}' WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1";
```

You're missing the commas between the columns:

```
$query = "UPDATE userprofile SET full_name='{$full_name}', aboutme='{$aboutme}',  friend='{$friend}' WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1";
```

And, for what it's worth, you're not properly using prepared statements - you're still setting the values directly into the query which is prone to SQL injection.

Try updating to:

```
$query = "UPDATE userprofile SET full_name=?, aboutme=?,  friend=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
if ($stmt) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $full_name, $aboutme, $friend, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: But it would still work properly without the `?` variables wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answers but not work on my case the problem in my php code was

```
$purchased_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['pdate']));
```

when i checked the database I found it only store the Year and stop after it saw -

so it return error we should get the date like this

```
$purchased_date = date('Ymd', strtotime($_POST['pdate']));
```

sorry If i have grammar mistakes